# How to move a value of array in an object to another key array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following key value object with a `change` value which tells me to add

```js
let change = {key: 23, value: 3}
    
let obj = {
  22: [7, 4, 2, 3],
  23: [1, 5, 6],
}
    
obj[change.key].push(change.value)
    
console.log(obj)
```

this results in

```
{
  22: [7, 4, 2, 3],
  23: [1, 5, 6, 3],
}
```

but what I want is for it to remove the old `22:3` and add it to `23`, so it becomes

```
{
  22: [7, 4, 2],
  23: [1, 5, 6, 3],
}
```

is there an efficient way to do that without doing full object scan to find where the `3` exists before?

the key and values are always unique

the method I thought of was to use `find` using

```
let fromKey = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].includes(change.value));
obj[fromKey] = obj[fromKey].filter(item => item !== change.value)
```

but I think it would be inefficient in the amount of values gets bigger and more spread

I am open to restructuring the format of the object.

it is later used like this

```js
let change = {key: 23, value: 3}
    
let obj = {
  22: [7, 4, 2, 3],
  23: [1, 5, 6],
}

let vals = {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c',
  4: 'd',
  5: 'e',
  6: 'f',
  7: 'g',

}
    
obj[change.key].push(change.value)
    
for (let k in obj) {
  let list = obj[k]
  for (let v of list) {
    console.log(k+': '+vals[v])
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have an idea of a restructuring? what is the purpose of the values of the arrays?

Comment: How big (i.e. how many integers) would you reasonably expect this to reach? It would have to be in the order of tens of thousands to even start to become noticable.

Comment: @NinaScholz the values are just keys to values like `{1: 'a', 2:'b', ...}`, I iterate over the `obj` keys later in `for loop` to print each key's value letter.  I will add an example now

Comment: @adsy maximum I believe is 5000

Comment: Tbh thats possibly small enough to not care. That will likely be imperceptible to a human. Try it with large sets, and then decide if you have a problem before over-optimizing too early.

Comment: "is there an efficient way to do that without doing full object scan to find where the 3 exists before?" how would you know where in the object to update it?

Comment: @adsy problem is that values changes every second that in a minute this would be near 1000 process

Comment: This kind of manipulation though is *exceptionally* fast. Far, far quicker than a second. You really need to check this, as what seems large to you its actually a trivial amount of computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, I would suggest writing your own data structure that maintains forward and reverse references to your values, for example `fwd` and `rev` below. The `set` function is careful to update both `fwd` and `rev` when a set operation is performed. The `toObject` function converts from your custom type to a simple javascript object.

```js
function Db() {
  const fwd = new Map
  const rev = new Map
  return { 
    set(k, v) {
      // remove old entry
      if (rev.has(v)) fwd.get(rev.get(v)).delete(v)
      // update reverse lookup
      rev.set(v, k)
      // add to existing fwd entry
      if (fwd.has(k)) fwd.get(k).add(v)
      // otherwise create new fwd entry
      else fwd.set(k, new Set([v]))
    },
    toObject() {
      return Object.fromEntries(
        Array.from(
          fwd.entries(),
          ([k, v]) => [k, Array.from(v)]
        )
      )
    }
  }
}

const db = Db()
db.set("fruit", "") // <- first in fruit
db.set("fruit", "")
db.set("fruit", "")
db.set("veggie", "")
db.set("veggie", "")
db.set("veggie", "") // <- move to veggie
console.log(db.toObject())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

Internally `fwd` and `rev` are represented like this -

```
fwd = Map {
  fruit: Set { ,  },
  veggie: Set { , ,  }
}

rev = Map {
  : fruit,
  : fruit,
  : veggie,
  : veggie,
  : veggie,
}
```

Verify the output of `toObject` below -

```js
{
  fruit: [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  veggie: [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]
}
```